# Эмуляция звонка на телефон, отладка

Tags: android, android-sdk

Каким образом можно эмулировать входящий звонок на реальном устройстве, для отладки приложения?

Comment: а зачем эмулировать, если можно взять и позвонить)

Comment: я думаю, простого способа нет в силу того, что это попросту ненужно. Намного проще позвонить по-настоящему

Comment: Возможно проще, когда у тебя есть несколько телефонов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Через Android Device Monitor можно. DDMS->Emulator Control[image: введите сюда описание изображения]